# XSLT pipeline : Error XPDY0002 - The context item for axis step fn:root(...)/element() is absent

Tags: saxon

Please, I need some help dealing with saxon api :)
I create a pipeline with 2 XsltTransform of the same xslt and when i run transform i get this error :

```
2019-01-24 11:32:15,673 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO e.s.e.x.XsltListener - file
2019-01-24 11:32:15,674 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO e.s.e.x.XsltListener - Error 
XPDY0002 while evaluating xsl:message content: The context item for axis 
step fn:root(...)/element() is absent
```

here is my xslt :

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:variable name="supp" as="xs:string" select="root()/*/name()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message select="$supp"/>
    <file/>
</xsl:template>
```

the first XsltTransform work fine but It seems that i have no context node during the second XstTransform running.

I use :

```
transformer1.setSource(source) : source is a SAXSource

transformer1.setDestination(transformr2)

transformr2.setDestination(serialiser)
```

According to documentation (XsltTransform.setInitialContextNode):
This value is ignored in the case where the XsltTransformer is used as the Destination of another process. In that case the initial context node will always be the document node of the document that is being streamed to this destination.

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

In general in XSLT 3 you need to distinguish between the initial match selection https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-initial-match-selection which is used to decide which template to apply first and the global context item https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-global-context-item that is used to evaluate global parameters and variables. I think you seem to expect that in your second stylesheet the result of your first acts as both but it seems, at least in your setup, Saxon does not assume that but only sets your initial match selection to the result of the first stylesheet. So try moving the `<xsl:variable name="supp" as="xs:string" select="root()/*/name()"/>` into the template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="supp" as="xs:string" select="root()/*/name()"/>
    <xsl:message select="$supp"/>
    <file/>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure there is another way, at least in the case of chaining two streaming transformations you can't the second stylesheet expect to have access to the whole result tree of the first to be used to evaluate global parameters or variables.